# Insert document only if not already exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating documents with

```
Subscription.create({ email: req.body.email }, (err, subscription) => {
  //
});
```

I have made the email field unique in my Mongoose schema, so it's not possible to create multiple docs with same email.

But I don't care whether a certain email already exists, so I don't want a duplicate error as I receive now. How can I insert only if the email doesn't exist already and not create if it does exist, but not tell the user?

I assume it's best practice not to tell the user if the email already exists in the database, since it can be used to test whether an email is associated with the site. It doesn't seem very problematic, but I still think it's better not to tell due to privacy concerns.

Comment: We just can find by email before create the document, no ?

Comment: As @BNilsou said, you just look in the DB before you create, with mongoose you can use the [findOne](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) query, also it's not a security issue telling the user "This email is already used", every website I've ever been to with a sign up form responds with "This email/username is already in use".

Comment: My experience is just that on my websites, even though I already signed up to the newsletter, I am still able to sign up again. But maybe I should consider letting the user know

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose you can use the pre function.

```
var schema = new Schema(..);
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // Check if the mail exists. If it does, just throw an exception
  // If not, just create the thing using next.
  next();
});
```

You should be careful to catch the exception and when you call the save function. I believe this will do the work.

Comment: Is this preferred to checking in the my controllers?

Comment: It's a matter of taste. I always prefer to use the built-in functions in the libraries (at least the famous ones) due to efficiency and so. Moreover, if you need to add more rules, you can go to the same place